# Postman Retry logic goes in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, postman

I am using postman for testing my API.

One of the API which takes some time to process the data I have added a retry logic to try  3 times to check if the end points work fine.

The initial value of `retryCount` is 3 which is set in the few test before this test where retry is executed.

Below is the code:

```
let retryCount = pm.environment.get('retryCount');
let responseData = pm.response.json();
console.log(responseData.data.events.length);
console.log(retryCount);
if(responseData.data.events.length == 0 && retryCount > 0)
{
    retryCount = retryCount - 1;
    console.log(retryCount);
    pm.environment.set('retryCount',retryCount);
    postman.setNextRequest("GetEvents");
}
else
{
    pm.environment.set('data-response',responseData.data);
}
```

After 3 retries it should stop. however, it goes in the infinite loop. The problem is occurring because the variable is always 3 when the next call happens it should reduce by 1 and eventually become 0.

what could be the reason that above code goes in infinite state.

Comment: is it going inside the if condition ?

Comment: "GetEvents" is the same request in which you have the script ?

Comment: yes GetEvents is the same request  where the script is.

Comment: it is going inside the if condition

Comment: what does the console.log(retry prints ? is it printing correctly ? 3,2,1 etc ? , are you reseting the value some where ? in the same request or in collection scripts ?

Comment: See the updated answer it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be reseting the value some where in collection scripts or some where elese in your collection. Create a new variable and try, use below method :

```
pm.variables.get("retryCounter")===undefined ? pm.variables.set('retryCounter',3):null

let responseData = pm.response.json();
console.log(responseData.data.events.length);

retryCount = pm.variables.get("retryCounter");
console.log(retryCount);
if(responseData.data.events.length === 0 && retryCount > 0)
{
    retryCount = retryCount - 1;
    console.log(retryCount);
    pm.variables.set('retryCounter',retryCount)
    //this gives this request name , you don't have to hardcode
    postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName);
}
else
{
    pm.environment.set('data-response',responseData.data);
}
```

Try this code , here we are using pm.variables.set  which creates local variables. As the life time of local variable is the entire collection run and after that it will be destroyed, so for every new collection run the value will be undefined.

we are setting the value to 3 if its undefined . and then sends the request till the value becomes less than 1.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it is indeed somewhere the value was getting reset now it works perfectly